# Jensen's inequality for Euclidean spaces with extended reals

Tags: convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

Let $X$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $p$ be a probability density function on $X$ (i.e. $\int_X p(x) dx = 1$), let $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ be a convex function with codomain in the *extended* reals. (This could be phrased more generally in terms of measure spaces, but for my purposes it suffices to consider the presented case where $X$ is just a subset of a finite-dimensional Euclidean space.) In that case do we have Jensen's inequality,

$$\phi\left(\int_X x \, p(x) dx\right) \leq \int_X \phi(x) p(x) dx,$$

even if $\phi$ is not lower semicontinuous?

There's quite a number of previous questions discussing related issues, but nothing that really seems to resolve this specific question. For instance the discussions in the following only consider the case where the domain of $\phi$ is in the real line rather than a general Euclidean space (relying on techniques that hold when the domain is an interval, but I'm not sure how to generalize them to Euclidean spaces):

[Counterexample to Jensen's Inequality when the convex function admits values in the extended real set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357656/counterexample-to-jensens-inequality-when-the-convex-function-admits-values-in)

[Counterexample to Jensen's inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300246/counterexample-to-jensens-inequality)

While the proofs here rely on the existence of a supporting hyperplane, which does not seem guaranteed if $\phi$ is not lsc (there is some discussion of this point in the answers in the second link but no resolution for the case where $\phi$ has values in the extended reals and hence may not be lsc):

[Jensen's inequality in measure theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662502/jensens-inequality-in-measure-theory)

[Jensen's inequality for integral without l.s.c. assumption](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909822/jensens-inequality-for-integral-without-l-s-c-assumption)

[A simpler proof of Jensen's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84424/a-simpler-proof-of-jensens-inequality) (This one is not precisely assuming a supporting hyperplane, but the claim that a convex function is everyhere equal to the supremum of its affine minorants requires some kind of closure condition in the general case.)

Comment: this answer has a nice proof if $\phi$ is lower semicontinuous https://math.stackexchange.com/a/171608/136544

Comment: you can set $X$ to $\mathbb R^n$ (by setting $\phi:=+\infty$ outside of $X$).

Comment: I believe that the claim is true without lower semicontinuity, but I am not able to rove it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, proofs along essentially those lines are given in some of the above links as well (those relying on a supporting hyperplane), but indeed the challenge is precisely in the construction of a suitable supporting/separating hyperplane when the convex function is not lsc. I am however starting to think that the proof in the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357656/counterexample-to-jensens-inequality-when-the-convex-function-admits-values-in for the 1-dimensional case may be generalizable to arbitrary finite dimension...

Comment: The idea is basically to reduce to the lsc case by redefining the function on a zero-measure set on its boundary such that it becomes lsc...but it does seem slightly annoying to find the best way to construct this, e.g. one could take the new values at those points to be defined via limits from the interior of its domain, but I'm not sure what is the cleanest way to ensure this yields lower semicontinuity. (Another option would be to take the lower convex envelope of the function, but it's perhaps not obvious whether this *only* redefines the function value on the required subspet.)

Comment: Okay on further consideration, I don't think the approach presented in that answer I linked is quite valid after all. Will have to think about another approach.